# JPA how to query the database without creating a table

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, annotations

I am using JPA and Spring for my db tasks and I need to have a join query like below in the JPA Repo class

```
@Query("SELECT 1 as id, COUNT(bill) as bills, ba.resource, MAX(b.updatedAt) as latestdate FROM Bill b join b.billComp ba where ba.comp.comp = ?1  group by ba.resource")
public List<BillCalc> findByBills(Long comp);
```

My Entity class is as below

```
@Entity
public class BillCalc {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer id;

@Column(name = "latestdate", nullable = false)
private Date latestdate;

@Column(name = "bills", nullable = false)
private Long bills;

@Column(name = "resource", nullable = false)
private String resource;
```

I cannot create a table for this and can someone help me in getting the mapping to work? It gives me an error saying cannot cast from Object to BillCalc.

I tried `@SubSelect` but it does not take parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. add a constructor to `BillCalc`.

   ```
   BillCalc(Integer id, long bills, String resouce, Date latestdate) {...}
   ```
2. then use a `Select new` query:

   ```
   SELECT new BillCalc(1, COUNT(bill), ba.resource, MAX(b.updatedAt)) 
       FROM Bill b join b.billComp ba
       WHERE ba.comp.comp = ?1  group by ba.resource")
   ```

@See Chapter 4.8.2 "Constructor Expressions in the SELECT Clause" in [JSR-000220 Enterprise JavaBeans 3.0 Final Release (persistence)](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/ejb-3_0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/)